# MongoDB not recognizing the dbpath

Tags: mongodb, database

I have an issue where `2.6.10 mongo` (have to use due to changes in `3.x` not being supported by our application) does not recognize the `dbpath` I've set.  I've checked the `mongod.cfg` file and made sure the `filepath` is intact.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that it's a firewall issue.  When I try to set the dbpath using the command '--dbpath' it locks up when listening for port 27017.

Comment: What is `filepath`? What does the mongod.cfg look like, and how is mongod started? Why would the program 'lock up' when trying to open a port? (firewalls don't work like that). What does `netcat -nlp` tell you? What OS are you using?